# Manual Elmah Logging dosnt work properly in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I used ELAMH 1.2 to log errors in MVC 5. It work well for 404 500... HTTP errors and in controller's catch blocks.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("test"));
        try
        {
            var a = 0;
            var b = 1 / a;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

i get two log for this code.
but it dosent work in a static class like below. i dont get any exception while running `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);`.

```
public static class FileUtility
{
    public static string SaveSampleFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {

            var b = 0;
            var  a = 1/b;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

no error log nothing happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also seen this problem when calling ELMAH logger without any HttpContext in class library projects.

I used the old manual way to get around this:

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(ex));
```